# How to write protect an usb stick

Tags: usb

I want to write protect an usb stick by using a command script, after selecting it.

So something with list disk and choice. So that I only have to execute the script and it will let me choose which usb stick I'd like to write protect. Perhaps someone has got any ideas?

Comment: First you don't provide your operating system. Second, unfortunately, we are not a code-writing service. Instead of simply asking for code to perform a particular task, please show us what you've tried so far (including any code you currently have) and where you're stuck so that we can help you with your specific problem. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Answer (score 3):

Not possible. A software-based solution will not provide any real security. You need a real hardware switch. That way, the thumb drive's controller would deny writes.

Comment: You could pull the stick out halfway through a write… that would do it, kind of ;-)  [Don't try this at home]

Comment: Now that sounds like a surefire way to corrupt the filesystem. :P

Comment: It would likely kick the firmware into write-protect, which is an answer … of sorts :P